# Hash a hexadecimal number using SHA-256 in java

Tags: java, hex, sha256

I have written a code to hash a hexadecimal number using SHA-256 in Java. Please see my code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger("f35b", 16);
        
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(x.byteValue());
        byte[] hashedXArray = md.digest();
        
        BigInteger hashedX = new BigInteger(hashedXArray);
        System.out.println(hashedX.toString(16));
        
    }
    
}
```

Its result is...

```
245843abef9e72e7efac30138a994bf6301e7e1d7d7042a33d42e863d2638811
```

Then I hashed the same input using another third party application with SHA-256. Its answer was completely different from above output. It is...

```
cd05094b5c5a5b80386da4fcfdd20e6ef5d363d97834ac8705e9832e6bd97f39
```

I still do not understand why my code result is far different from the actual value of sha256 of hexadecimal "f35b" and how can I resolve my code?

Comment: *Error 1:* `x.byteValue()` is `91` aka `0x5b`. It is not a 2-byte array with value `{ 0xf3, 0x5b }`. --- *Error 2:* If e.g. `hashedXArray = { 0xca, 0x86, 0x42 }`. the code prints `-3579be`. --- Don't use `BigInteger` for converting `byte[]` to/from hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `BigInteger`:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class HashIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        byte[] input = new byte[] { (byte) 0xf3, (byte) 0x5b };
        System.out.println(toHexString(input));
        
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(input);
        byte[] hashedXArray = md.digest();
        
        System.out.println(toHexString(hashedXArray));
    }
    
    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        Formatter result = new Formatter();
        try (result) {
            for (var b : bytes) {
                result.format("%02x", b & 0xff);
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> f35b
> cd05094b5c5a5b80386da4fcfdd20e6ef5d363d97834ac8705e9832e6bd97f39

---

If input *must* be string, add:

```
    private static byte[] fromHexString(String text) {
        assert text.length()%2 == 0 : "invalid text length";
        
        byte[] result = new byte[text.length()/2];
        for (int i = 0;  i < text.length(); i += 2) {
            result[i/2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(text.substring(i, i+2), 16);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and call as `byte[] input = fromHexString("f35b");`

<sup>just one solution of many</sup>

---

One reason not to use `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("00001234", 16);
byte[] input = x.toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

leading zeros are removed, results in

> `[18, 52]`

or

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("FFFF", 16);
byte[] input = x.toByteArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
```

additional zero is added (make it positive):

> `[0, -1, -1]`

---

Why getting wrong results:

```
BigInteger x = new BigInteger("f35b", 16);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(x.byteValue()));
```

results in `5b`, that is, the low byte of given `BigInteger`.